# How can I link a related contact in Contact Layout Editor?

Tags: contact-layout-editor

I'm displaying a contact on the Contact Layout Editor based on a custom relationship, which is working fine. I've figured out how to display it as plain text, or as an editable text field (which updates the organization name on the related contact if edited).

Is there a way I can display it as a link to the related contact record?

Comment: Depending on how you're determining what relationship to display this might be an alternative - the contacts display as links: https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/org.wikimedia.relationshipblock. And it's compatible with contact layout editor.

Comment: That's perfect for my needs! Do you want to convert the comment to an answer?

Comment: Great! Copied to the answer box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you're determining what relationship to display this might be an alternative - the contacts display as links: https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/org.wikimedia.relationshipblock. And it's compatible with contact layout editor.